# Not able to set screensaver idle time as root

Tags: macos, plist, cfpreferences

Script i used is

```
#!/bin/sh
# grab current user
curUser=`ls -l /dev/console | cut -d " " -f 4`

# grab the system's uuid
if [[ `ioreg -rd1 -c IOPlatformExpertDevice | grep -i "UUID" | cut -c27-50` != "00000000-0000-1000-8000-" ]]; then
        macUUID=`ioreg -rd1 -c IOPlatformExpertDevice | grep -i "UUID" | cut -c27-62`
fi
defaults write /Users/$curUser/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.screensaver.$macUUID.plist idleTime -int 900
```

But later when i go and see Desktop&screensaver settings in mac . I did not find start after 15min.

But when i gave

```
defaults read /Users/$curUser/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.screensaver.$macUUID.plist idleTime
```

output is 900

even i tried by killing  cfprefsd daemon but still this new value is not getting set

```
killall cfprefsd
```

Please can anyone tell me where do i did mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried an alternate script and it worked. But before executing this command we should make sure that we quit system preferences.

```
#!/bin/bash
currentuser=`ls -l /dev/console | cut -d " " -f 4`
sudo -u $currentuser defaults -currentHost write com.apple.screensaver idleTime -int "120"

sudo -u $currentuser defaults -currentHost read com.apple.screensaver idleTime
```